# JAVA EE Stateless EJB IllegalArgumentException: Can not set field

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, illegalargumentexception

I'm heaving some trouble while learning ejb. All I want is write a simple app operatign on database. Here's my code:

**Servlet - Main.java**

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "Main", urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class Main extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
private NoteSB noteSB;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        List<Note> notes = noteSB.getNotes();
        for( int i=0,len=notes.size() ; i<len ; ++i ) {
            out.println(notes.get(i));
        }

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}


}
```

**Entity - Note.java**

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTES")
public class Note implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String note;
    private Timestamp date;

    public Note(){}

    public Note(String note, Timestamp date) {
        this.note = note;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Note)) {
            return false;
        }
        Note other = (Note) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note["+ this.date +"]: " + this.note;
    }

}
```

**Stateless Session bean - NoteSB.java**

```
    package main;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class NoteSB {


    @PersistenceContext(name = "jee-warPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void newNote(Note n) {
        em.persist(n);
    }

    public List<Note> getNotes() {
        return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM NOTES").getResultList();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

**persistance.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="jee-warPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/DefaultDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here's my stack trace:

```
    Info:   file:/C:/Users/BB/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jee/jee-war/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_jee-warPU logout successful
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Info:   file:/C:/Users/BB/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jee/jee-war/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_jee-warPU login successful
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB NoteSB: [java:global/jee-war/NoteSB, java:global/jee-war/NoteSB!main.NoteSB]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Info:   Loading application [jee-war] at [/jee-war]
Info:   jee-war was successfully deployed in 783 milliseconds.
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet Main as unavailable
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Main]: Allocate exception for servlet Main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set main.NoteSB field main.Main.noteSB to main.Main
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:688)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I will appreciate any help! I've tried many tutorials and options and still can't figure out what it is all about. Digging the stack trace is just getting me crazy, I partially understand the errors but don't know what to do, please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing visible accessor methods for your `noteSB` field. Add the following getter and setter methods to your `Main` class:

```
public class Main extends HttpServlet {

    // all your current code here

    public NoteSB getNoteSB() {
        return this.noteSB;
    }

    public void setNoteSB(NoteSB noteSB) {
        this.noteSB = noteSB;
    }
}
```

Refer to the [JavaBean specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). Specifically this passage:

> **7.1 Accessor methods**
>
> Properties are always accessed via method calls on their owning
>   object. For readable properties there will be a *getter* method to
>   read the property value. For writable properties there will be a
>   *setter* method to allow the property value to be updated. Thus even when a script writer types in something such as “b.Label = foo” there
>   is still a method call into the target object to set the property, and
>   the target object has full programmatic control.
>
> So properties need not just be simple data fields, they can actually
>   be computed values. Updates may have various programmatic side
>   effects. For example, changing a bean’s background color property
>   might also cause the bean to be repainted with the new color.
>
> For simple properties the accessor type signatures are:
>
> ```
> void setFoo(PropertyType value); // simple setter
> PropertyType getFoo(); // simple getter
> ```

Comment: This behabior is stranger for me. Can you explain why for successfull injection  glassfish needs getter and setter? Are any link to spec exist?

Comment: It might work without the getter and setter if the variable were declared as `public NoteSB noteSB;`, but that would violate encapsulation.

Comment: We have deal with weblogic, jboss and widfly and they not require public modificator in field declaration with @EJB annotation (injection point), we use private or protected - this access limitations are not a barrier for injection. I can't find proof in specification, which describe this moment. Do you know?

Comment: Which specification do you mean? Please be aware, when you place the `@EJB` annotation on a field declaration, that the default behavior is to use *getter* and *setter* methods by reflection. If such accessors are not present, only then will EJB look directly at the field declaration by reflection. This is because the [Enterprise JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html) is an extension of the JavaBean specification referenced in my answer.

Comment: And what I must to do in the case of Glassfish, if I want to hide EJB annotated field for internal purpose, hide from external view? In the EJB specification can't found any information about injection and field modifiers limitations, will read more closely. On my mind Glassfish behavior described in main question of the thread is misteken.

Comment: It's the other way around. JBoss and WebLogic are mistaken if they're quiet about a private field with no accessor methods in a JavaBean. If you want to hide the fields, perhaps try decreasing the visibility of the accessor methods?